# Cassandra and pig integration cause error during startup

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I have a problem trying to start sample pig and cassandra config (from examples/pig)

```
2012-07-27 14:34:49,020 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve CassandraStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

It looks like some classpath problem still I can't find the reason. ANyone knows what jars might cause this problem ? 
I had set my variables to:

```
export PIG_HOME=/home/sebastian/cassandra/source/pig-0.10.0
export PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS=localhost
export PIG_RPC_PORT=9160
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner
```

Comment: I had a similar error and it was caused by not fully qualifying the classnane for CassandraStorage. Using org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

CassandraStorage is in org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig and needs the Cassandra jars to run.

Comment: hey i'm pretty sure they are on the classpath... can you tell me which jars are the required ones ?

Comment: I use maven to set up my class paths, but the dependencies I use refer to hector-core-1.0.1.jar, cassandra-thrift-1.0.6.jar and pig-0.9.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the following in your class path
    PIG_JAR=//pig-0.11.0.jar
    HADOOP_CLASSPATH=//hadoop-1.0.4/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar
    HADOOP_CONF=//hadoop-1.0.4/conf

Add all the above in the 
Do these changes in pig_cassandra
Let me know if you have the same problem. I will share the code.